# Se escribe "trío pitagórico" o "trío Pitagórico"?

Tags: gramática, ortografía, adjetivos, uso-de-mayúsculas

Pitagórico viene de Pitágoras, que es un nombre, pero no tengo claro si esta conjugación del nombre va con mayúscula o minúscula. Espero me puedan responder y explicar el porqué.

Answer (score 9):

Se deletrean los adjetivos derivados de nombres propios con minúscula:

> #### [pitagórico, ca](https://dle.rae.es/?id=TERaq0e)
>
> `Del lat. Pythagorĭcus, y este del gr. Πυθαγορικός Pythagorikós.`
>
> 1. adj. Fil. Perteneciente o relativo a Pitágoras, filósofo y matemático del siglo VI a. C., o al pitagorismo.
> 2. adj. Fil. Seguidor de Pitágoras o del pitagorismo. Apl. a pers., u. t. c. s.
>
> > letra pitagórica
> >
> > tabla pitagórica

Otros ejemplos (eso también se aplica a los sustantivos derivados):

- [lopista](https://dle.rae.es/?id=NbzY4wF)
- [kantiano](https://dle.rae.es/?id=MfxwxOn) (kantismo)
- [hegeliano](https://dle.rae.es/?id=K5VvoqA) (hegelianismo)
- la obra [shakesperiana](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Xm5LIB4)
- los entremeses [cervantinos](https://dle.rae.es/?id=8OqJMA6) (cervantismo)
  <sub>/ cervantescos / cervánticos (cervantista, cervantófila)</sub>

No obstante, nota que los nombres propios crudos (sustantivos) conservan su letra inicial mayúscula:

- síndrome de [Down](https://dle.rae.es/?id=EArj9SL)
- enfermedad de [Bright](https://dle.rae.es/?id=66OJF1B)
- enfermedad de [Alzhéimer](https://dle.rae.es/?id=2B3Izdh)

Comment: Sobre el uso de las mayúsculas, el punto 4 del DPD está muy bien detallado: http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=BapzSnotjD6n0vZiTp